# Find div inside a div and remove it?

Tags: jquery

I want to remove div inside the div with class chartsbar
Here is my html code

```
<div class="chartsbar" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; left: 27.28%; display: none; height: 0%; background-color: rgb(7, 134, 205); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 0.9730252100840335%; text-align: left; " rel="0" title="09-09-2012 - 0 (0%)">

<div style="text-align:center">
0
</div>

<span style="display: block; width: 100%; position: absolute; bottom: 0; text-align: center; background-color: #0786CD;">
09-09-2012
</span>

</div>
```

i tried

```
$('.chartsbar').find('div').first().remove();
```

but not seems to be working.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$('.chartsbar div').remove();
```

It should work!

Keep it simple!

**EDIT**

If you only want to remove the first one:

```
$('.chartsbar div:first').remove();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with a simple selector. This will remove the first div child.

```
$(".chartsbar > div:first-child").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
$('.chartsbar').find('div:eq(0)').remove();
```

or directly use

```
$('.chartsbar div').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.chartsbar > div').remove();
```

Or:

```
$('.chartsbar div').remove();
```

Check [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/bUWGh/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('.chartsbar').children().first().remove()`